# Couldn't start client Terraform LS - VSCode - Big Sur - macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terraform

Couldn't start client Terraform LS

Uninstalled everything (Plugin, VSCode, Terraform, Terraform-LS)
Reinstalled everything (Homebrew)

Same error every time...

terraform -version
Terraform v1.0.3
on darwin_amd64

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.70.0

terraform-ls -version
0.20.0

VSCode
Version: 1.58.2

HashiCorp Terraform Plugin
Version: 2.14.0

macOS Big Sur
Version: 11.5.1

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am suppressing the desire to introduce my laptop to tannerite

Comment: Do you open a file (.tf) or directory?
And possibly such kind of question is more suitable for [github issue in hashicorp vscode-terraform repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/issues).